# UWP drag and drop on Mobile Emulator

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mobile, uwp

I have implemented drag and drop using `UIElement.StartDragAsync`.

The code is below. This code works perfectly on my Desktop,
but does not work when running on the mobile emulator. What happens is DragCompleted is always fired instantaneously after `PointerPress -> OnDragStarting`. This happens when I use both Single Point Touch Input & Single Point Mouse Touch Input on the emulator. No exception is thrown and I don't use error-handling code.

```
private void OnDragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Data.SetText("DRAG");
    }

private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CanDragDrop) return;

        var pointerPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement);
        var dragOp = StartDragAsync(pointerPoint);
        dragOp.Completed += DragCompleted;
    }

private void DragCompleted(IAsyncOperation<DataPackageOperation> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
    {
        _dragOperation = null;
        if (asyncInfo.GetResults() == DataPackageOperation.Move)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: _and I don't use error-handling code._

Nice edit jobsworth.